# link_to_function and jquery does not work together in rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The following link_to_function works:

```
 <%= link_to_function "click", "alert(Hallo world!" %>
```

However, with jquery, the following does not work:

```
 <%= link_to_function "click", "$('#std').append('<p>my friend!</p>')" %>
```

In application.html.erb, there are:

```
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
   <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

jquery seems functioning well. Any thoughts about the problem? Thanks.

Also here is the api definition in rails 3.1.3 for link_to_function:

```
link_to_function(name, function, html_options={})

Returns a link whose onclick handler triggers the passed JavaScript.

The helper receives a name, JavaScript code, and an optional hash of HTML options. The name is used as the link text and the JavaScript code goes into the onclick attribute. If html_options has an :onclick, that one is put before function. Once all the JavaScript is set, the helper appends “; return false;”.

The href attribute of the tag is set to “#” unless html_options has one.

link_to_function "Greeting", "alert('Hello world!')", :class => "nav_link"
# => <a class="nav_link" href="#" onclick="alert('Hello world!'); return false;">Greeting</a>
```

UPDATE: here is the html sour code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#std').append('&lt;p&gt;my friend!&lt;/p&gt;'); return false;">test</a>
```

Comment: Inspect the HTML/JS output of your Rails application. Post it here.

Comment: just updated with html source code.

Comment: how do I check if my asset compiling is right? The app uses js.erb to serve a few ajax calls without any problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the obtrusive way to write javascript. I would write something like this:

```
<%= link_to "click", "#", :id=>"click" %>
```

**Update**

You should add document ready to have the proper binding.

Then in your application.js

```
$(function() {
  $("#click").click(function(e){
    $('#std').append('<p>my friend!</p>');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: still no reaction after clicking "add std". Here is the html source:   <a href="#" id="click_std">Click</a>. Used :id => "click_std"

Comment: Please try the updated code. And make sure that your `application.js` is loaded.

Comment: Copied the code over and still no reaction. seems no reason. How to check if application.js is loaded?

Comment: Opened the web page, and firebug. It shows "no javascript on this page".

Comment: after removing a bug in .js.coffee file, the application.js loaded successfully. And it appended as well. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of appending a paragraph, how can I append a render as following: escape_javascript render(:file => 'standards/_standards.html.erb', :locals => {:f => f}, :object => @rfq.standards.build )? Need to pass in a form var f into the function. thanks.

Comment: I guess you want to add nested fields dynamically for your form, this is a bit more complicated, please check out this project, to get an idea how to do it: `https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/tree/jquery` also there is a similar screencast about the topic. `http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1`

Comment: Yes, I want to add nested fields to the form. For rails 3.1.0, link_to_function is not the same as what described in Ryan's episode. The idea is the same however the actual coding has changed. That's what I am working on now. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6871/discussion-between-dombesz-and-user938363)

Comment: There is a gem for doing all the logic `https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form` , if you still like to roll your own solution, which is good, take a look at this https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/blob/master/lib/nested_form/builder_mixin.rb and https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_nested_form.js

Answer (score 1):

are you using prototype too? if not then following code should work.
add this in your view.

```
<%= link_to "click", "javascript:", :onclick => "call_function();" %>
```

in your script file add following code.

```
function call_function () {
  $('#std').append('<p>my friend!</p>');
}
```

Comment: No reaction to the click. Same problem.